# Nito.AsyncEx async producer/consumer queue doesn't process

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, async-await

I am trying to create a "message pump"-like custom Synchronization Context which runs on a thread.

The program is Silverlight 5, and the sync queue is from the [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) nuget (v3.0.1) by Stephen Cleary.

**The code** (sorry for the length, comments/debug intentionally included):

```
public sealed class ThreadSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext, IDisposable
{

    /// <summary>The queue of work items.</summary>
    private readonly AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>> syncQueue =
        new AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>>();

    private readonly Thread thread = null;

    public ThreadSynchronizationContext()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("------------------------");
        Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - starting worker thread sync context!");
        Debug.WriteLine("------------------------");

        // using this hack so the new thread will start running before this function returns
        using (var hack = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            thread = new Thread(async obj =>
            {
                SetSynchronizationContext(obj as SynchronizationContext);

                hack.Set();

                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - awaiting queue available...");
                    while (await syncQueue.OutputAvailableAsync())
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("awaiting queue item...");
                        var workItem = await syncQueue.TryDequeueAsync();
                        Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - queue item received!");
                        if (workItem.Success)
                        {
                            workItem.Item.Key(workItem.Item.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - queue finished :(");
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - queue exception :((");
                }
            });
            thread.Start(this);

            hack.WaitOne();

            Debug.WriteLine("worker thread: " + WorkerThreadId);
        }
    }

    public int WorkerThreadId { get { return thread.ManagedThreadId; } }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        syncQueue.Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>Dispatches an asynchronous message to the synchronization context.</summary>
    /// <param name="d">The System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback delegate to call.</param>
    /// <param name="state">The object passed to the delegate.</param>
    public async override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        if (d == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("d");

        Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - enqueuing item...");
        await syncQueue.EnqueueAsync(new KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>(d, state));
        Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - item enqueued.");
    }

    /// <summary>Dispatches a synchronous message to the synchronization context.</summary>
    /// <param name="d">The System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback delegate to call.</param>
    /// <param name="state">The object passed to the delegate.</param>
    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        if (d == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("d");

        using (var handledEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            Post(SendOrPostCallback_BlockingWrapper, Tuple.Create(d, state, handledEvent));
            Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - waiting for blocking wrapper!");
            handledEvent.WaitOne();
            Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - blocking wrapper finished.");
        }
    }

    private static void SendOrPostCallback_BlockingWrapper(object state)
    {
        var innerCallback = (state as Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object, ManualResetEvent>);
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - call callback from blocking wrapper...");
            innerCallback.Item1(innerCallback.Item2);
            Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - blocking wrapper callback finished.");
        }
        finally
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - setting handle from blocking wrapper!");
            innerCallback.Item3.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

When I start the app, and Post a few delegates to the context, this is the output:

```
------------------------
thread 1 - starting worker thread sync context!
------------------------
thread 17 - awaiting queue available...
worker thread: 17
thread 1 - enqueuing item...
thread 8 - enqueuing item...
thread 8 - item enqueued.
thread 1 - item enqueued.
thread 1 - waiting for blocking wrapper!
```

Basically, the program freezes at the line `handledEvent.WaitOne();` of the `Send()` method, as if the queue never started processing added items.

I'm kinda stumped, any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a bit tricky, but there's a good clue in the fact that you'll see your "enqueueing item..." debug output *twice* when you only call `Send` *once*.

What's actually happening is that the custom synchronization context is being picked up by the `await`s within the thread's main delegate. So, it'll try to queue its queue-processing code into its own queue.

To break it down:

- The thread delegate starts executing and hits the `await syncQueue.OutputAvailableAsync()` line.
- At this point, the thread delegate registers its continuation with the current synchronization context (the instance of `ThreadSynchronizationContext`) and then returns (causing the thread to exit).
- When the calling code calls `Send`, it enqueues an item to the queue, which causes `OutputAvailableAsync` to complete.
- The thread delegate then attempts to continue executing by `Post`ing to the captured `ThreadSynchronizationContext`.

If you want a single-threaded synchronization context, then you shouldn't have an asynchronous thread delegate at all. Instead, just use the synchronous APIs:

```
thread = new Thread(obj =>
{
    SetSynchronizationContext(obj as SynchronizationContext);

    hack.Set();

    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - awaiting queue available...");
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("awaiting queue item...");
            var workItem = syncQueue.TryDequeue();
            Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - queue item received!");
            if (!workItem.Success)
                break;
            workItem.Item.Key(workItem.Item.Value);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - queue finished :(");
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - queue exception :((");
    }
});
```

In fact, I recommend avoiding `async void` completely, so I'd suggest making `Post` a synchronous method also (it's still "asynchronous" in the sense that it's not executing its `SendOrPostCallback` delegate immediately; it is synchronously *enqueueing*):

```
public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
{
    if (d == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("d");

    Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - enqueuing item...");
    syncQueue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>(d, state));
    Debug.WriteLine("thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - item enqueued.");
}
```

---

Or, you could save yourself the pain of all this and just use [the `AsyncContextThread` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) that is already part of AsyncEx. `AsyncContextThread` uses its own single-threaded synchronization context internally.